# Get all data from code-behind using AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I know this question has been asked tens of times, but actually my question is a bit different.

I want to send a request using AJAX to the code-behind to retrieve all the records from the attached database, but I don't have any parameters to pass I just want to send the request and then get a JSON object contains all the table data, and here is the difference in my question as all the questions I've seen included passing some params.

Here is the AJAX code in which I'm trying to send the request:

```
 var data;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Register.aspx/getRecords",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.d);
                    data = response;
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                console.log("Status: " + textStatus); console.log(" Error: " + errorThrown); 
            } 
            });
```

And here is the code-behind where I'm trying to fetch the data from the database:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static List<Employee> getRecords()
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    List<Employee> dataRows = new List<Employee>();

    con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\Shebel Ali\\Desktop\\SampleDB.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    con.Open();
    cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Employee";

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    int i3 = 0;
    int i4 = 0;
    int i5 = 0;
    int i6 = 0;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Employee getEmp = new Employee(reader.GetValue(i1).ToString(), reader.GetValue(i2).ToString(), reader.GetValue(i3).ToString(), reader.GetValue(i4).ToString(), reader.GetValue(i5).ToString(), reader.GetValue(i6).ToString());
        i1++;
        i2++;
        i3++;
        i4++;
        i5++;
        i6++;
        dataRows.Add(getEmp);

    }

    return dataRows;
}
```

plz ignore the inproper ways to code some stuff, just focus on the error below

What is happening is that the I'm getting an error with the AJAX request,
here is the error I'm getting:

Status: parsererror.

Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: I am not sure but you can try something like following.
try returning serialized string from server side code. see below.

return JsonConvert.Serialize(dataRows);

Comment: It seems you got spatial character in json data.

Comment: i agree with Maharshi's idea. you're trying to return a .NET type when it should be a string. also try `return dataRows.ToString();` at least for testing.